# $Z$ score probability

Tags: normal-distribution

I was given a question where I was supposed to find the probability of obtaining $y$ between two scores, however when I input my answer it tells me that I'm wrong, the question is given below along with my answer to the question:

**Question**
For a normal distribution with sample mean $= -19$ and standard deviation $= 6.85$ find $p( -16.15 \leq y \leq -15.27 )$, where $y$ is a random draw from the normal distribution. 
Round to $4$ decimal places.

**My answer**
I obtained the $z$ scores for both the $y$ values $-15.27$ and $-16.15$ and their
respective $z$ scores are $0.5445$ and $0.4161$. The probability under the curve with a $z$ score of $0.5445$ is $0.7054$ and the probability under the curve with a $z$ score of $0.4161$ is $0.6628$. With those two probabilities, I obtained the difference (getting $0.0426$) and I put in that answer and was told that I was wrong. Can someone give me insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your CDF table for the normal distribution only allows you to get a couple decimals, so you're saying $\Phi(.5445) \approx \Phi(.54) = .7054$ which (apparently) isn't a good enough approximation.

$\Phi(.5445)- \Phi(.4161) \approx .706951 - .661332 = .045619 \approx .04562$

I found these values using [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Phi%28.5445%29) [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Phi%28.4161%29).

Answer (score 0):

You should state what type of technology you are allowed to use.
If you use a regular CAS-enabled calculator and plug in the command:
normCdf(-16.15,-15.27,-19,6.85)
meaning:
Dear Calculator, please tell me the probability for a normal distribution with a mean of -19 and standard deviation 6.85 that a random draw from the normal distribution lies between -15.27 and -16.15.

You should get the value 0.046

Not sure what your mistake is and, I am not sure what you mean by the probability under the cureve with a z-score of 0.4161, since the probability of a certain z-score is always 0.

Comment: Okay, it's extremely tedious to restart my module because it takes a long time to complete however the answer it provided after providing a wrong answer x amount of times was "0.0426000000000001" this module is foolish to say the least.

Comment: Of course $4$ decimal places is absurd, models are just not that good. But for example when you quote the probability that $Z\le 0.4161$, you quote the answer in my standard normal table that corresponds to $\Pr(Z\le 0.42)$. Obviously you cannot get $4$ decimal place accuracy in that way. You can squeeze an extra place out of a table by interpolating, but for $2$ more you need to use other machinery. Plenty of programs will do it.

Comment: Further comment: The problem says *sample mean*. As to standard deviation, it is not clear whether they mean standard deviation or sample standard deviation. How big the sample? Say it is kind of big. Still, it is absurd to claim $4$-digit accuracy probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't maintained enough numerical precision. Specifically, it looks like you rounded your $z$-scores to two significant figures. Your result is the probability of a $z$-score between 0.42 and 0.54, not between 0.4161 and 0.5445.